# How can I edit my phone number on Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story

How can I edit my phone number, the one that appears when I download my developer story as a PDF?

I don't see it under **Edit Profile & Settings**.

Answer (score 4):

It is present in Job Match Preferences menu in **Edit Profile $ Settings**.

[image]
Here is the url:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current

Comment: ok.. the general url can be set as `current` instead of random userid though

Comment: True, good point.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your phone number in "Job match preferences" under "Edit Profile & Settings", here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/3320006 (3320006 is your profile ID, or you can use "current").

[image]